# Multiple datasets not working with Twitter Typeahead/Bloodhound

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to working on Typeahead and Bloodhound and i'am using latest js. Below is my sample code.
Html:

```
<div id="multiple-datasets">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="NBA and NHL teams">
</div>
```

Here is the script:

```
var nbaTeams = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('team'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: '{ "names": ["Aaron  Kreisler","Adam  Alder","Adam  Preece"]}'
      });

   var nhlTeams = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('team'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: '{ "titles": ["Acute Chronic Pancreatitis Program", "Aerodigestive Program", "Analytical Imaging and Modeling Center (AIM)"]}'

      });

  $('#multiple-datasets .typeahead').typeahead({           
        highlight: true
      },
      {
        name: 'nba-teams',
        display: 'team',
        source: nbaTeams,
        templates: {
          header: '<h3 class="league-name">NBA Teams</h3>'
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'nhl-teams',
        display: 'team',
        source: nhlTeams,
        templates: {
          header: '<h3 class="league-name">NHL Teams</h3>'
        }
 });
```

Any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[bloodhound multiple dataset cause typeahead template issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669638/bloodhound-multiple-dataset-cause-typeahead-template-issue)

I post a question about that too (link on top), but I'v multiple dataset working, just the templates part broken.
It's the code from [officials examples](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#multiple-datasets) but without the json file, can you post it on a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

`display` property seems to be wrong (blind c&p issue?); as given in [doc](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets) `display` should point to the `data-field` within each matching data-row

Pls try the edited code-block below:

```
var nbaTeams = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('team'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: ["Aaron  Kreisler","Adam  Alder","Adam  Preece"]
  });

var nhlTeams = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('team'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: ["Acute Chronic Pancreatitis Program", "Aerodigestive Program", "Analytical Imaging and Modeling Center (AIM)"]
  });

$('#multiple-datasets .typeahead').typeahead({           
    highlight: true
  },
  {
    name: 'nba-teams',
    source: nbaTeams,
    templates: {
      header: '<h3 class="league-name">NBA Teams</h3>'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'nhl-teams',
    source: nhlTeams,
    templates: {
      header: '<h3 class="league-name">NHL Teams</h3>'
    }
 });
```